# How to convince dpkg that libssl1.0.2 is >= libssl1.0.0?

Tags: debian, dpkg, libraries, ssl, dependencies

I am trying to install a 3rd party .deb package that I have installed before on Debian 8.  But I cannot install on a fresh Debian 9 setup because I get the following error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of parity:
 parity depends on libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0); however:
  Package libssl1.0.0 is not installed.
```

I *do* have libssl1.0.2 installed.  But it is not being recognized as ">= libssl1.0.0" so I wonder how to fix this.

1. Do I install libssl1.0.0 manually?  If so, how?
2. Do I symlink something?  If so, what?
3. Something else?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`libssl1.0.2` and `libssl1.0.0` are different packages, providing incompatible libraries; that’s why you can’t satisfy a `libssl1.0.0` dependency using `libssl1.0.2`.

To satisfy your package’s requirements, I’d suggest adding the Debian 8 repositories to your configuration, since Debian 8 is still supported (so if necessary you’ll get security updates). To do so, edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and copy every `stretch` line, replacing `stretch` with `jessie` (so you end up with *both* `stretch` and `jessie` lines). Then run `apt update`, and `apt install libssl1.0.0` should work.

Alternatively, you can [download the package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libssl1.0.0) (look for your architecture at the bottom of the page), and install it with `dpkg -i`.

In both cases, `apt-mark auto libssl1.0.0` will help: that way the package will be considered for auto-removal, should it become unnecessary in the future.

Comment: If I have the repos for both stretch and jessie, how will conflicts be avoided on packages in both repos?

Comment: `apt` will pick later versions of packages from similarly-configured repositories; so in your case, it will favour Jessie, and will only use the Stretch repositories for packages which are no longer in Stretch (such as `libssl1.0.0`), as long as they don’t conflict with installed Jessie packages.